# Eloquent Query with Left join returning double the sum of the actual values in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by, left-join

I am trying to get the total of receipts and deductions of all the bills of a work. There are 2 entries in receipts with amounts Rs.80,000 and Rs.10,000.
There are 2 entries in deductions with amounts Rs.500 and Rs.100

The result I am getting is:
Total deductions - Rs.1,200 (double of the actual Rs.600)
Total receipts - Rs.1,80,000 (double of the actual Rs.90,000)

My Eloquent query is as follows:

```
$bills = bills::leftjoin('receipts', 'receipts.billId', 'bills.billId')->leftjoin('deductions', 'deductions.billId', 'bills.billId')
                ->select('bills.billId', 'bills.billDate', 'bills.billNumber', 'bills.billStatus', 'bills.billAmount', DB::raw('SUM(deductions.deductionAmount) as totalDeductions'), DB::raw('SUM(receipts.receiptAmount) as totalReceipts'))
                ->groupBy('bills.billId', 'bills.billDate', 'bills.billNumber', 'bills.billStatus', 'bills.billAmount')
                ->where('bills.workId', $workId)
                ->get();
```

SQL Fiddle link - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf46cb/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the grouping and SUMs then you can see all of the rows that are returned, and that your left joins are causing a duplication error:

```
SELECT `bills`.`billId`, `bills`.`billDate`, `bills`.`billNumber`, `bills`.`billAmount`,
        deductions.deductionAmount,
        receipts.receiptAmount
FROM `bills` left join `receipts` on `receipts`.`billId` = `bills`.`billId`
             left join `deductions` on `deductions`.`billId` = `bills`.`billId`
WHERE `bills`.`workId` = 6
```

You can avoid this with sub-queries, but I have no idea how to do that with Eloquent:

```
SELECT b.`billId`, b.`billDate`, b.`billNumber`, b.`billAmount`,
        (SELECT SUM(deductionAmount) FROM deductions WHERE BillID = b.BillId) as totalDeductions,
        (SELECT SUM(receiptAmount) FROM receipts WHERE BillID = b.BillId) as totalReceipts
FROM `bills` b
WHERE b.`workId` = 6
```

Comment: Thank you Russell. It's working now. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how it would be done in Eloquent:

```
$bills = bills::select('bills.billId', 'bills.billDate', 'bills.billNumber', 'bills.billStatus', 'bills.billAmount', 
                 DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(deductionAmount) FROM deductions WHERE billId = bills.billId) as totalDeductions"),
                 DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(receiptAmount) FROM receipts WHERE billId = bills.billId) as totalReceipts"))
                   ->groupBy('bills.billId', 'bills.billDate', 'bills.billNumber', 'bills.billStatus', 'bills.billAmount')
                   ->where('bills.workId', $workId)
                   ->get();
```